# Is it possible to refer to another element inside a JS array/object

Tags: javascript, arrays

Somehow I can't find the right term to search for this problem, basically I want to do this with javascript:

```
var demo = [{part1: 'a', part2: 'b', part3: this.part1 + this.part2}];
```

Now I think this is not possible, but since I can't determine why and what to call this construct, maybe somebody here can.

- **is there a term or accurate description for this situation?**
- can this be solved in js?

thanks!

EDIT:

due to the comments, I need to be more specific:

```
var demo = [
{
    text: 'long text',
    action: function(xy) { log(text);}
},
{
    text: 'long text2',
    action: function(xy) { log(text);}
},
];
```

the goal is to let action log the text defined with it.

---

EDIT2: as @EnigmaRM has cleared nearly everything up, this is a Bonus

instead of

```
 demo[1].action()
```

solve it while action is called this way:

```
 var someCaller = demo[1].action;
 someCaller();
```

Comment: Try `var obj = { part1: 'a', part2: 'b' }; obj.part3 = obj.part1 + obj.part2; demo = [obj];`.

Comment: could you write `var demo = [{part1: 'a', part2: 'b', part3: demo[0].part1 + demo[0].part2}];`? or you need to use `this`?

Comment: What would `{part1: 'a', part2: this.part1 + this.part3, part3: 'b'}` look like though? How would it assign the value given that `part3` is part of the object, but not yet defined? `part3` should probably be a function

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan guess my debug space was cluddered, this does not work ..

Comment: I tested on chrome console and it works fine

Comment: yes, did so too, but had defined demo once before, if you don't clean up you get false results - copy paste your solution into chrom console and rename demo to something new and unique ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily split out the dynamic portion `demo.part3` or `demo.action` and call it after the object has been defined.

```
var demo = {
    text: 'long text',
};
demo.action = function(xy){console.log(this.text)};
```

Similarily,

```
var demo = {part1: 'a', part2: 'b'};
demo.part3 = demo.part1 + demo.part2;
// {part1: "a", part2: "b", part3: "ab"}
```

If you are wanting to keep your array of objects format

```
var demo = [{
        part1: 'a', 
        part2: 'b', 
        part3: function(){return this.part1 + this.part2;}
    }
];
```

Then in the use of `part3` you would call it as `demo[0].part3()` which would give you `'ab'`

---

You keep modifying what you're trying to accomplish slightly. here is the updated example with your latest edits.

```
var demo = [
    {
        text: 'long text',
        action: function(xy) {
            console.log(this.text);
        }
    },
    {
        text: 'long text2',
        action: function(xy) {
            console.log(this.text);
        }
    }
];
```

invoke & results

```
demo[0].action() // long text
demo[1].action() // long text2
```

---

**Edit2 answer**

```
var someCaller = demo[1].action();
someCaller; //long text2
```

I believe you want the result of `demo[1].action()` to be passed to the variable, rather than assigning the entire function to the variable as you currently have. So just adding `()` to the assignment invokes the function to run and pass the result to `someCaller`.

It needs to be done this way because of our use of `this`. This always refers to the parent object it is referencing. So if you do `var someCaller = demo[1].action`, `this` now references 'somecaller', which does not have the other properties of the original `demo` object, and thus you get `undefined`.

Comment: Does this meet your requirement? or are you looking for something different?

Comment: nearly, my real world problem has a bit of a different scope, because the action is called by some other function - it's quite a mess - but you helped me a lot to understand and I now have a solution - so thanks! I'll play with this some more and will accept your answer if there is nothing more accurate (which is my assumption)

Comment: If you post more specific code that is relevant to your real world issue, then we can get closer. But glad this has helped you get on the right track.

Comment: see the new edit, but I have to leave now, see you guys tomorrow, thanks for all the help!

Comment: although I do want to pass it without (), you explained well what the consequences are, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,

```
var newObj = { part1: 'a', part2: 'b' }; 
newObj.part3 = newObj.part1 + newObj.part2; 
demo = [newObj];
```

or

```
var demo = [{part1: 'a', part2: 'b', part3: demo[0].part1 + demo[0].part2}];
```